# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{\ln(y)} = e^{\,\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln(y)}$?

Tags: limits, exponentiation

In the above limit $y = x ^{\frac 1x}$. Is the above a limit or an exponent property?

Thanks in advance.

Context (Last paragraph): http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx

Comment: Your equation is not true for the standard real numbers. The left hand side is $\lim_{x\to\infty}x$ which is undefined, and the right hand side has an undefined limit in the exponent. If you use the affine extended real number system, you could say both sides equal $+\infty$: Is that your question?

Comment: @RoryDaulton "lim x as x→∞ which is undefined" this is false, "lim of x as x→∞ equals ∞

Comment: Doy you mean $x=\infty$, not a smth like $x=a$?

Comment: You cannot blame others for editing your question. It was not clear what that $y$ was before you provide the link.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you must have meant $x$ inside the $\ln$.

Comment: oh yes, it is extremely important that $y$ is defined to be $x^{1/x}$.

Comment: @muaddib Does it makes any difference?

Comment: I just meant, I understand the problem now.  It actually still holds true for the original reason I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true for continuous functions that when $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = z$ exists (so $z$ finite), that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(z_n) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n)$$

In the problem above we can let $z_n = \log(x^n)^{1/x_n}$ for some sequence $x_n \to \infty$.  In that case, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = 0$$

Now since $e^x$ is a continuous function we have:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp{(\log(x_n)^{1/x_n})} = \exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(x_n)^{1/x_n}) = 1$$

Comment: I'd say this is only half true. Suppose he had e ^ - ln(x). then lim(x->inf)(e^(-ln(x)) = 0, but -ln(x) itself has no limit (it goes to minus infinity)

Answer (score 2):

The theorem cited by muaddib is valid when n is natural. Nevertheless, in your question, you want that x be real. And Jane Smith's aswer makes senses, but it's pretty qualitativy. I will try to prove the following statement:

If $f$ is continuous in an interval I$\in \mathbb{R}$ and $L \in \mathbb{}$ I, then $$\ lim_{x\to\ p}f(g(x))= f(lim_{x\to\ p}g(x))$$ $$\ lim_{x\to\infty}f(g(x))= f(lim_{x\to\infty }g(x))$$

Since the limits of g at right member of equation exist.

We can do $lim_{x\to\ p}g(x)=L$, then for all $\epsilon >0$, we have a $\delta$ such that $$|x-p|<\delta => |g(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Since $f$ is continuous, then for all $\epsilon_1 >0$, we have a $\delta_1$

$$|g(x)-L|<\delta_1 => |f(g(x))-f(L)|<\epsilon_1$$

It's enough makes $\delta_1=\epsilon$. We can do that because $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, so it can assume any real positve value. In the second case $x \to \infty$, it's suffcient you switch $p$ for $\infty$ and do $x>\delta$. The rest is the same. The case $x \to -\infty$ is analogous to case $x \to \infty$.

If $|lim_{x\to p}g(x)|= \infty$, then for all $\epsilon >0$, we have a $\delta$ such that $$|x-p|<\delta => |g(x)|>\epsilon$$

Now we have to investigate the behavior of $f(y)$ when $|lim_{x\to p} y|= \infty$. In case $|lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)|= \infty$, it's analogous. Therefore, in any cases above, you only have to investigate the limit of g.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been already answered here:

> Q: I was studying L'Hopital's rule and how to deal with indeterminate
>   forms of the type 0^0. It's not clear to me how lim e^f(x) = e^lim
>   f(x).
>
> A: You can move the limit inside the exponential, because the
>   exponential itself doesn't have problem spots ("is continuous
>   everywhere"), so it is only the f(x) inside that you have to deal with
>   regarding the limit.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/limits-involving-exponential-functions.330771/

Answer (score 0):

As exponential is a continuous function we can pass the limits inside the function

Lemma: If a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to x$ and we have a continuous function f then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)=f(x)$
And in your case $f(x)=e^x$
But the for this to be true the limits needs to exist

Comment: Is that still true for "$x=\infty$"? (BTW, the question is changed)

Comment: @John For the limit to exist it has to converge to a  value in $\mathbb{R}$ .So indeed it's not valid if we are not in the extended real number system.